# Print listbox items

Tags: c#

I have a list box in a form and I want to print all the items from it. How can I make it please? I tried this code but it did not print.

```
e.Graphics.DrawString(lstServicesForPrinting.Text, 
    fontRegular, Brushes.Black, 1350, 200);
```

Comment: You have to enumerate through the items in the list.

Comment: can you give me an example how this can be done? please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using a WinForms `ListBox`, you can enumerate all its items, adding each's ToString() output to a `StringBuilder` and then use that in your `DrawString()` call, like this:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach(var item in lstServicesForPrinting.Items)
{
  sb.AppendFormat("{0} ", item.ToString());
}
e.Graphics.DrawString(sb.ToString(), fontRegular, brushes.Black, 1350, 200);
```

You can apply any formatting to how you want to separate the list's items in the `AppendFormat` string.